# Data not being fetched in a a partial template

Tags: php, html, css, database, angular

This is Angular and php code. There is no error in console and still the data is not being fetched in the partial template.I checked my PHP connection and its working fine though the data is not displayed in my partial.Please help me with issue and Thank you in advance.

menu.html(Partial Template)

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController">
<figure class="menu_jumbotron">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
  <li>Menu</li>
</ul>
</figure>
<div class="menu">
<h1><i>{{title}}</i></h1>
<div class="menu_button">
<figure>
  <div>
    <span>Breakfast</span>
    <span>100% Organic</span>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div>
    <span>Lunch</span>
    <span>100% Organic</span>
  </div>
</figure>
    <figure>
  <div>
    <span>Dinner</span>
    <span>100% Organic</span>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div>
    <span>Beverages</span>
    <span>100% Organic</span>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div>
    <span>Desserts</span>
    <span>100% Organic</span>
  </div>
</figure>
</div>
<div>
<table style="background-color:white; margin-left:500px">
    <thead>
        <th style="border:1px solid red">Name</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid red">Price</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid red">Meal Type</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in all_items" >
            <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Price }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.MealType }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

popdata.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$db = "meoan_organics";

$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);

if(!$con)
{
die('Unsuccessful Connection');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `meoan_all_food_items`";

$q = $con->query($sql);

$data = array();

if($q->num_rows >0)
{
while($row = $q->fetch_object())
{
$data[] = $row; 
}
} 
else
{
$data[] = null;
}

$con->close();
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

script.js

```
/// <reference path="route.js" />

app.controller("MenuController",['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope,$http,$log) {
        $scope.title = "Our Menu";

        $http.get('database/popdata.php')
        .then(function(data){
        $scope.all_items = data;
        }),function(err){
        $log.error(err);
        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.mealType }}</td>
```

instead of:

```
        <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Price }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.MealType }}</td>
```

Comment: can you show the result of console.log($scope.all_items); after http.get?